# ¿como excluir fines de semana en input date?

Tags: jquery, django, bootstrap-3

Necesito limitar la entrada de fecha de entrada de un formulario a 5 días laborales.

Ahora mismo solo limito para no seleccionar fechas anteriores al día de hoy pero necesito también limitar las fechas posteriores.

Ahora mismo tengo esto

```
<form method="post">
<div class="row">
    <div class="form-class col-sm-4 col-md-2 ">
        <label>Fecha Inicio</label>
        <div class="form-group"><label class="sr-only control-label" for="id_fecha_ini">Fecha ini</label><input name="fecha_ini" value="['16/03/18 12:46']" id="id_fecha_ini" title="" class="form-control hasDatepicker" type="text"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-class col-sm-4 col-md-2 date">
        <label>Fecha Fin</label>
        <div class="form-group"><label class="sr-only control-label" for="id_fecha_fin">Fecha fin</label><input name="fecha_fin" value="['17/03/18 16:35']" id="id_fecha_fin" title="" class="form-control hasDatepicker" type="text"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-class col-sm-4 col-md-2">
        <label>Precio Envio</label>
        <div class="form-group"><label class="sr-only control-label" for="id_precio_oferta">Precio oferta</label><input name="precio_oferta" value="0" id="id_precio_oferta" required="" title="" class="form-control" type="number"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-class col-sm-4 col-md-4">
        <label>Texto Envio</label>
        <div class="form-group"><label class="sr-only control-label" for="id_texto_oferta">Texto oferta</label><textarea name="texto_oferta" rows="10" cols="40" title="" id="id_texto_oferta" maxlength="225" class="form-control"></textarea></div>
    </div>

</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-disk"></span> Guardar </button>
</div>
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#id_fecha_ini,#id_fecha_fin').datetimepicker({locale:'es', sideBySide: true, minDate: new Date()});
    });
</script>
```

Comment: La respuesta está ya hecha. Para añadir sabados, en la condicion pon `(day != 0 && day != 6)`. Ejemplo online: http://jsfiddle.net/9o58juvq/2/

Comment: ¿y si quiero limitarla a 5 días solamente? que solo pueda seleccionar uno de los 5 dias siguientes a la fecha actual

Comment: `maxDate: '+5d'` hace un maximo de 5 dias, pero si vas a quitar findes, pon `maxDate: '+1w'` para que si el 5nto dia cae en finde, puedas seleccionar el lunes